# How to throw exception if assigning to object property?

Tags: javascript

My demo:

```
let NullReferenceException = (function () {
    class NullReferenceException {
        constructor(message) {
            let _ = {
                'Message': message
            };
            return _;
        }
    }
    return NullReferenceException;
}());

let string = (function () {
    let _source = Symbol('string');

    class string {
        constructor(value) {
            this[_source] = value || null;

            if (value) this.Length = value.length;

            // invalid syntax
            this.Length = value ? value.length : 

            throw new 
            NullReferenceException('Object reference not set to an instance of an object.');
        }
    }
    return string;
}());
```

Useage:

```
try {
    let s = new string(); // Don't throw exception here

    // throw exception here (reason: cannot assign to "Length" property of null)
    let length = s.Length; 
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.Message);
}
```

My goal: After defining `s` variable, no exception would be thrown inside the `string` constructor. But, `s.Length` does it.

If I use

```
if (value) this.Length = value.length;
```

it wouldn't throw any exception. Just returning `undefined`.

```
let length = s.Length; // undefined
```

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a getter for the `Length` property with the appropriate logic, rather than trying to set it in advance:

```
// assuming _source has already been defined
class string {
    constructor(value) {
        this[_source] = value || null;
    }

    get Length () {
        const value = this[_source];
        if (value) {
            return value.length;
        } else {
            throw new NullReferenceException('Object reference not set to an instance of an object.');
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get